# Exact solutions of a linear second order differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, special-functions

```
DSolve[ y''[x] + (a - (b x^2 - c) x^2) y[x] == 0, y[x], x]
```

I couldn't solve this equation, please help

Comment: There is no solution for the anharmonic oscillator in terms of the elementary or any standard special function as far as I know.

Comment: I get a solution in terms of [`DifferentialRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferentialRoot.html).  What version are using?

Comment: You should mention what is your motivation to find a solution. The solution space is five-dimentional (two numbers form initial/boundary conditions and three constants) and so it not a well posed question even though one can find an  exact  general solution.

Answer (score 6):

Since the *12.1* version of *Mathematica* we can **solve exactly** this differential equation **explicitly in a symbolic form** involving tri-confluent Heun function.

```
solHT[x_] = DSolveValue[ y''[x] + (a - (b*x^2 - c)*x^2)*y[x] == 0, y[x], x]
```

> ```
> (C[2] HeunT[-a - c^2/(4b), -2I Sqrt[-b], -I c/Sqrt[-b], 0, -2I Sqrt[-b], 
> x])/E^(((I/6) x (3c - 2b x^2))/Sqrt[-b]) + 
> E^(((I/6) x (3c - 2b x^2))/Sqrt[-b]) C[1]^2 HeunT[-a - c^2/(4b), 2I Sqrt[-b], 
> I c/Sqrt[-b], 0, 2I Sqrt[-b], x]
> ```

```
solHT[x] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

The general solution involves three constants of the original differential equation $a, b$ and $c$ as well as two integration constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.
We can also solve the equation prescribing symbolic constants and initial/boundary conditions, e.g.

```
With[{a = 3, b = 2, c = 1},
  TraditionalForm[ ds = DSolveValue[{y''[x] + (a - (b x^2 - c)x^2)y[x] == 0,
                                      y[1]==0,y'[0]==1}, y[x], x]//FullSimplify]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[ ds, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

let's exploit another conditions:

```
With[{a = 1, b =-1/4, c = 1/2},
  TraditionalForm[ ds2 = DSolveValue[{y''[x] + (a - (b x^2 - c)x^2)y[x] == 0,
                                       y[0]==2,y'[0]==0}, y[x], x]//FullSimplify]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[ ds2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thick, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image]

Exact symbolic solutions can be approximated with available analytic tools, e.g.

```
Series[ ds2, {x, 0, 14}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica can't solve analytically,but numerical yes can.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = 3;
b = 2;
c = 1;
eq = {y''[x] + (a - (b*x^2 - c)*x^2)*y[x] == 0, y[1] == 0, y'[0] == 1};
sol = First@NDSolve[eq, y, {x, -2, 2}];
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotLegends -> {"y(x)"}, AxesLabel -> {x, y[x]}]
```

[image]

**MAPLE** analytical solution:

[image]

```
y[x] == 
C[1]*HT[(2^(1/3)*3^(2/3)*(4*a*b + c^2))/(8*b^(4/3)), 
0, (-c*2^(1/3)*3^(1/3))/(2*b^(2/3)), (-2^(1/3)*3^(2/3)*b^(1/6)*x)/
3]*Exp[(x*(2*b*x^2 - 3*c))/(6*Sqrt[b])] + 
C[2]*HT[(2^(1/3)*3^(2/3)*(4*a*b + c^2))/(8*b^(4/3)), 
0, (-c*2^(1/3)*3^(1/3))/(2*b^(2/3)), (2^(1/3)*3^(2/3)*b^(1/6)*x)/
3]*Exp[(-(b*x^2 - 3/2*c)*x)/(3*Sqrt[b])]
```

You can be expressed this equation by the series:

$$y(x)=c_1 \text{HT1} \exp \left(\frac{x \left(2 b x^2-3 c\right)}{6
   \sqrt{b}}\right)+c_2 \text{HT2} \exp \left(-\frac{\left(b x^2-\frac{3
   c}{2}\right) x}{3 \sqrt{b}}\right)$$

were **HT1** and **HT2** is:

[image]

and

[image]

> **References for Triconfluent Heun function:**
>
> 1.Decarreau, A.; Dumont-Lepage, M.C.; Maroni, P.; Robert, A.; and Ronveaux, A. "Formes Canoniques de Equations confluentes de l'equation de Heun".
>   Annales de la Societe Scientifique de Bruxelles. Vol. 92 I-II, (1978): 53-78.
>
> 2.Ronveaux, A. ed. Heun's Differential Equations. Oxford University Press, 1995.
>
> 3.Slavyanov, S.Y., and Lay, W. Special Functions, A Unified Theory Based on Singularities. Oxford Mathematical Monographs, 2000.

Comment: So this can justify the idea that Maple is more advanced in the solution of Differential Equations than Mathematica?

Comment: @dimitris. Yes is more advanced http://12000.org/my_notes/kamek/version_1/KERNEL/KEse1.htm#x3-20000