# Confluent Heun function

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

Does the confluent Heun function exist in Mathematica?

I try to evaluate the following,

```
DSolve[(1 - 2*M/r)^2*R''[r] + (1 - 2*M/r)*2*M/r^2*
R'[r] + (c^2 + 2*M*m^2/r)*R[r] == 0, R[r], r, Assumptions -> {m > 0, M > 0, c > 0}]
```

but there are no results. Also, using Maple, my friend show that the solutions is confluent Heun function. Can anybody help me to understand what I do wrong?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94856/differential-equation-solution, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139428/what-are-the-limitation-on-current-mathematicas-ability-to-solving-a-sturm-liou

Comment: Currently, the Heun functions aren't yet implemented in *Mathematica*.

Comment: `Maple` is more advanced in the solution of Differential Equations than `Mathematica`.

Comment: What does this differential equation describe? What are initial/boundary conditions?

Comment: @Artes mentioned equation describes a dynamical proccess with black hole background

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov I've expected that, I have provided here a few answers related to Schwarzschild geometry e.g. [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214063/the-time-like-geodesics-orbits-in-the-schwarzschild-spacetime/214076#214076), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/how-to-calculate-scalar-curvature-ricci-tensor-and-christoffel-symbols-in-mathem/8908#8908). Would you mind adding more details and specifying a bit what kind of process is it?  Why is this equation linear, does it follow a linearization procedure or just by chance?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov   Could you add more details and specify what kind of process is it or send appropriate link? How could this equation be derived?

Comment: Unfortunately, even tho the Heun functions are now built-in, `DSolve[]` still returns a `DifferentialRoot[]` solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 5 Heun functions will be available in version 12.1 of Mathematica, so that we will be able to solve Heun-type of equations in build-in Mathematica functions.

Comment: This is certainly something to look forward to; as noted in the comments, there have been situations where Maple's support for Heun functions has made it more helpful than *Mathematica*.