# The time-like geodesics (orbits) in the Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, physics, differential-geometry

I am trying to plot Schwarzschild's orbit without invoking the geodesic equation. 
As a reference I am using Chandrasekhar's Book (*The Mathematical theory of Black Holes,* Oxford University Press). In page 98 of the [book](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/The_Mathematical_Theory_of_Black_Holes.html?id=LBOVcrzFfhsC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) the equation(Eqn.94) is given

$$\left( \frac{du}{d\phi} \right) ^2=2Mu^3-u^2+\frac{2M}{L^2}u-\frac{1-E^2}{L^2}$$

The plots should come like the plots given in page 116 onwards.

I used [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) in Mathematica

```
E2 = 0.3; L = 2.5; M = 1;

Chandra1 = 
 NDSolve[
   {u'[ϕ] - (2 M u[ϕ]^3 + u[ϕ]^2 -(2 M)/L^2 u[ϕ] +(1 - E2^2)/L^2)^(1/2) == 0, u[0] == 0}, 
   u, {ϕ, -π, π}]

PolarPlot[Evaluate[{1/u[ϕ]} /. Chandra1], {ϕ, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

But it is not working, instead of reporting the following error:

> ```
>  NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 4331206 steps reached at the point
>  t == 0.654767877735252`
> ```

Please help me how to tackle this type of problem.

Comment: I have solved your equation exactly, however there must be somoething wrong with your initial condition `u[0]==0`. Then you evaluate `1/u[ϕ]`...

Comment: In the 4-th edit you've added by mistake the power `0.5` to the equation in `NDSolve`. By the way, I guess the title e.g. "Finding orbits in the Schwarzschild spacetime" would be more adequate.  To make your post self-contained You should explain why You are going to see the polar plot of $1/u(\phi)$ and not just $u(\phi)$. What does function $u(\phi)$ describes and how it is related the actual orbit of a point particle in the Schwarzschild spacetime?

Answer (score 22):

Studying basic solutions at the theoretical physics it is advantageous when one can get  an exact solution. At the first sight one can see that the solution can be given in terms of elliptic functions (and elliptic integrals), though there are some tricks to remember in order to play with them seamlessly.

Instead of dealing with approximate numbers we are going to use exact numbers or more generally symbols `M, L, E2` and rewrite your differential equation (you have been trying to solve in `Mathematica`  different one) as your wrote it in TeX:

```
(u'[ϕ])^2 - 2M u[ϕ]^3 + u[ϕ]^2 - (2M)/L^2 u[ϕ] + (1 - E2^2)/L^2 == 0
```

Now we can observe that our equation can be rewritten to the canonical Weierstrass form $w'(x)^2 -4w(x)^3+g_2 w(x)+g_3 =0$ substituting $u(\phi) \mapsto a w(\phi) + b$, and in order to determine `a` and `b` we evaluate

```
((u'[ϕ])^2 - 2M u[ϕ]^3 + u[ϕ]^2 - (2M)/L^2 u[ϕ] + (1 - E2^2)/L^2) 1/a^2 ==0 /.{
   u[ϕ] -> a w[ϕ] + b, u'[ϕ] -> a w'[ϕ]} // Collect[#, w[ϕ], Simplify] &
```

> ```
> -((E2^2 + (1 + b^2 L^2) (-1 + 2 b M))/(a^2 L^2)) + (2(b - 3 b^2 M - M/L^2) w[ϕ])/a
>   + (1 - 6 b M) w[ϕ]^2 - 2a M w[ϕ]^3 + w'[ϕ]^2 == 0
> ```

immediatelly we can find `a` and `b`

```
Solve[{(1 - 6 b M) == 0, 2 a M == 4}, {a, b}]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 2/M, b -> 1/(6 M)}}
> ```

and so the canonical Weierstrass form is

```
(((u'[ϕ])^2 - 2M u[ϕ]^3 + u[ϕ]^2 - (2M)/L^2 u[ϕ] + (1 - E2^2)/L^2) 1/a^2/. {
 u[ϕ] -> 2/M w[ϕ] + 1/(6M), u'[ϕ] -> 2/M w'[ϕ]}//Expand//Simplify[ #,{a ==2/M, 
                                                                      b ==1/(6M)}]&) == 0
```

> ```
>  (L^2 + (36 - 54E2^2) M^2)/(216L^2) + (1/12 - M^2/L^2) w[ϕ] - 4w[ϕ]^3 + w'[ϕ]^2 == 0
> ```

and consequently

```
g2 = -((-18L^2 + 216M^2)/(216L^2)); g3 = -((-L^2 - 36M^2 + 54E2^2 M^2)/(216 L^2));

 DSolve[(L^2 + (36 - 54E2^2) M^2)/(216 L^2) + (1/12 - M^2/L^2) w[ϕ] - 4 w[ϕ]^3
         + w'[ϕ]^2 == 0, w[ϕ], ϕ]
```

> ```
>  {{w[ϕ] -> WeierstrassP[ϕ - C[1], {-((-18 L^2 + 216M^2)/(216L^2)),
>                               -((-L^2 - 36 M^2 + 54 E2^2 M^2)/(216L^2))}]},
>   {w[ϕ] -> WeierstrassP[ϕ + C[1], {-((-18 L^2 + 216M^2)/(216L^2)),
>                               -((-L^2 - 36 M^2 + 54 E2^2 M^2)/(216L^2))}]}}
> ```

We are going to use a more general initial condition $u(0)=c$ and so we can determine `C[1]` from  `u[0]==  2/M w[ϕ] + 1/(6M) == c` :

```
Solve[2/M w[0] + 1/(6 M) == c, w[0]]
```

> ```
>  {{w[0] -> 1/12 (-1 + 6 c M)}}
> ```

That is, we can put

```
C[1] -> InverseWeierstrassP[1/12 (-1 + 6c M), {g2, g3}]
```

(or `C[1] -> -InverseWeierstrassP[1/12 (-1 + 6c M), {g2, g3}]` where `g2, g3` are the same as above and finally denoting the solution by `uw` we can get:

```
uw[ϕ_, c_, M_, L_, E2_] := 
  With[{g2 = -((-18 L^2 + 216 M^2)/(216 L^2)), 
        g3 = -((-L^2 - 36 M^2 + 54 E2^2 M^2)/(216 L^2))}, 
        2/M WeierstrassP[ϕ - InverseWeierstrassP[1/12 (-1 + 6 c M), {g2, g3}], {g2, g3}]
        + 1/(6 M)]
```

We have provided a general symbolic solution, for any values of $M, L, E$.

**Edit**

In order to replicate the orbits  from Chandrasekhar's book we have to get appropriate parameters $M, L, E$ as well as `c`, nevertheless those plots were drawn in a different setting, namely using parameters $l, e$ instead of $L, E$.

The original question **does not contain sufficent information** to plot appropriate orbits despite prompting in comments to complete the post with necessary details.  One has to get through ~$30$ pages long subsection $19\;$ ***The geodesics in the Schwarzschild space-time: the time-like geodesics*** in Chandrasekhar's book.   Although the starting point in the book is the equation $(94)$, then after appropriate transformations Chandrasekhar arrives to a relation expressing the angle  $\phi$ as a function (incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind $F$ modulo certain elementary translations and rescalings) of another variable $\chi$ related to $u = 1/r$, where $r$ is the radial variable in the spherically symmetric four-dimensional Lorentzian manifold- the Schwarzschild space-time.
$$ u=\frac{1+e \cos(\chi)}{l} $$
Parameters $l$ and $e$ are constant and counterparts respectively of  latus rectum and eccentricity, while $L$ and $E$ are the first integrals of motion being conterparts of angular momentum and energy. To identify `L` and `E2` i.e. $L$ and $E$ in terms of `l` and `e` i.e. $l$ and $e$ we define two indentically equal polynomials of the third order:

```
f[u_]  := 2 M u^3 - u^2 + (2 M)/L^2 u - (1 - E2^2)/L^2       
f1[u_] := 2 M (u - (1 - e)/l) (u - (1 + e)/l) (u - (1/(2 M) - 2/l))
```

and a simple function:

```
rel[M_, l_, e_] := {M, L, E2} /. ToRules @ 
  Reduce[
    Join[
      Thread[
        Coefficient[f[u, M, L, E2] - f1[u, M, l, e], u, {0,1}] == {0, 0}], 
      {L > 0, E2 > 0, M > 0}],
    {L, E2}]
```

we choose plots $a, b, c, d, f$ rom the book  for which $(M, l, e)$ are:

```
Mle = {{3/14, 11, 1/2}, {3/14, 15/2, 1/2}, {3/14, 3, 1/2}, {3/14, 3/2, 1/2},
       {3/14, 9/7, 0}}
```

then $(M,L,E)$ are

```
MLE2 = rel @@@ Mle
```

> ```
> {{3/14, 22 Sqrt[3/577], Sqrt[43790/44429]}, {3/14, 15/Sqrt[127], 16 Sqrt[17/4445]},
>  {3/14, 6/Sqrt[43], Sqrt[286/301]}, {3/14, Sqrt[3/5], 4 Sqrt[2/35]}, 
>  {3/14, (3 Sqrt[3])/7, (2 Sqrt[2])/3}}
> ```

Now we replicate graphics (we have to to use `Re` before `WeierstrassP` even though in our cases values of functions are real because there may appear small imaginary part (usually we use `Chop` instead of `Re`) see e.g. this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164927/optimization-of-ode-with-respect-to-the-initial-condition/164949#164949))

**(a)**

```
PolarPlot[ Re[1/uw[ϕ, 1/10, 3/14, 22 Sqrt[3/577], Sqrt[43790/44429]]],
           {ϕ, 0, 24 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

**(b)**

```
PolarPlot[ Re[1/uw[ϕ, 5/30, 3/14, 15/Sqrt[127], 16 Sqrt[17/4445]]],
           {ϕ, 0, 16 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

**(c)**

```
PolarPlot[ Re[1/uw[ϕ, 4/18, 3/14, 6/Sqrt[43], Sqrt[286/301]]],
           {ϕ, 0, 12 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

**(d)**

```
PolarPlot[{ Re[1/uw[ϕ, 1/3, 3/14, Sqrt[3/5], 4 Sqrt[2/35]]], 
            Re[1/u[ϕ, 3, 3/14, Sqrt[3/5], 4 Sqrt[2/35]]]}, 
          {ϕ, 0, 16 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

**(f)**

```
PolarPlot[ Re[1/uw[ϕ, 5, 3/14, (3 Sqrt[3])/7, (2 Sqrt[2])/3]], 
           {ϕ, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

To add another plots with imaginary eccentricity we should slightly modify the function `rel`, that would be a simple exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for a very good answer. I'll wait a bit with acceptance to encourage others with different approaches as using NDSolve. I want to use the value of Energy (E2), angular momentum(L) and mass (M) with the specific value.

Comment: @ricci1729 You are welcome. You can specify al these parameters symbolically, as well as $u(0)=c$.  You have used initially $u(0)=0$ which is incompatibile with using afetrwards $1/u(x)$, this is why I decided to use $u(0)=c$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. One naive question of why it is not working with NDSolve? Is it because of u(0)= 0? Or some other techniques to be employed?

Comment: You can get the same solution with `NDSolve` however you have used a different equation, (check it carefully!).  I had got initially certain solution with `NDSolve` and then observed that the equation was wrong. Nonetheless I've been interested with your question because I wanted to provide  exact solutions. It would be constructive if you provide in your question full system of equations to make your question more practical, also for radial function, not only for $u(\phi)$.  without changing your original goal.

Comment: @ricci1729 Anyway you could use e.g. my old package [How to calculate scalar curvature Ricci tensor and Christoffel symbols in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/how-to-calculate-scalar-curvature-ricci-tensor-and-christoffel-symbols-in-mathem/8908#8908) to avoid too  long calculations with a pencil.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate it very much though I have written a code for myself for computing Ricci, Riemann, Weyl, etc your's one has some nice quick way to deal curvatures.

Comment: I don't understand this part regarding NDSolve . Caan you please take some time to elaborate it. I have changed the initial condition from u(0)=0 to u(0)= 1. Chandra1 = 
 NDSolve[{u'[\[Phi]] - (2 M u[\[Phi]]^3 - 
       u[\[Phi]]^2 + (2 M)/L^2 u[\[Phi]] - (1 - E2^2)/E2^2)^(1/2) == 
    0, u[0] == 1}, u, {\[Phi], -\[Pi], 0.1}]       But still it is not working..

Comment: @ricci1729  You have used in `Chandra1` this equation: `u'[ϕ] -( (2 M u[ϕ]^3 + u[ϕ]^2 -(2 M)/L^2 u[ϕ] +(1 - E2^2)/L^2)^(1/2))^0.5 == 0` which is different than your original equation from Chandrasekhar's book,  I wanted to play  a bit with your code and evaluated `PolarPlot[ Evaluate[{1/u[ϕ]} /. Chandra1], {ϕ, -Pi, Pi}] // Quiet`. Then stopped with `NDSolve`and played with quite laborious symbolic approach.

Comment: Probably I learned a lot discussing with you rather than seeing the Mathematica books. Can you suggest a good reference where I can learn to deal with more orbits equations (I mean I want the plots like in Chandrasekhar's books)?

Comment: @ricci1729 I have looked into Chnadrasekhar's book and understood the meaning of the variable $u$, nonetheless the page 116 couldn't be seen with books.google.co.in... Send me an appropriate picture you wanted to reproduce with Mathematica. Today I have not enugh time, however tomorow evening I will  try to edit my answer and complete it with specific plots. Nonetheless You should complete your question with appropriate information.

Answer (score 8):

I like the analytical solution @Artes. Nevertheless, if we need to find a numerical solution using `NDSolve[]`, then we can differentiate the equation and use the first-order equation at one point as a boundary condition, for example,

```
E2 = 3/10; L = 5/2; M = 1;
eq = {u''[x] == 3 M u[x]^2 - u[x] + M/L^2, u[0] == 4/3, 
  u'[0] == -(Sqrt[(54743/3)]/75)};
U = NDSolveValue[eq, u, {x, 0, 4.5}]
```

Compare this solution with the analytical solution:

```
 u[\[Phi]_, c_, M_, L_, E2_] := 
     With[{g2 = -((-18 L^2 + 216 M^2)/(216 L^2)), 
       g3 = -((-L^2 - 36 M^2 + 54 E2^2 M^2)/(216 L^2))}, 
      2/M WeierstrassP[\[Phi] - 
          InverseWeierstrassP[1/12 (-1 + 6 c M), {g2, g3}], {g2, g3}] + 
       1/(6 M)]
{PolarPlot[Re[1/U[x]], {x, 0, 4.5}, PlotRange -> All], 
 PolarPlot[1/u[x, 4/3, 1, 5/2, 3/10], {x, 0, 4.5}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: I am also trying to understand this, My queries are how you are choosing the values for parameter 'x' which you have taken here (x,0,4.3), and you are doing with 2nd order differential equation, Is this possible to do with 1st ODE.

Comment: @JeevithaT.U. First-order ODE should be used as it is in the book. Otherwise, solutions to the equation are lost. But there are two branches, therefore, with numerical integration, it is more convenient to use ODEs of the second order. I took the initial data to compare with the analytical solution.

Comment: I got an answer to my question which I have asked, to connect with this I am writing my reply through this since I don't have enough point to ask in the comment section. `E2 = 0.3; L = 2.5; M = 1; Chandra2 = NDSolve[{u'[π]^2 - (2 M u[π]^3 + u[π]^2 - (2 M)/L^2 u[π] + (1 - E2^2)/L^2) == 0, u[0] == 4/3}, u, {π, 0, 1.1}] PolarPlot[Evaluate[{1/u[π]} /. Chandra2], {π, 0, 1.1}]`

Comment: @Alex Trounev I have done for First-order ODE which is given in the book (Chandrasekhar). As you mention in the comment I have taken the initial data but I am not getting the exact plots like yours. Can you please let me know how to modify the code, keeping that in mind I wish to continue with First Order ODE. Thanks in advance.