# Get the trajectory of an object in a gravitational field

Tags: differential-equations

Given the initial position and velocity, I want get the trajectory of an object in a gravitational field. Instead of using Kepler's Laws, I want to solve the following differential equations:

[image]

```
DSolve[{x[0] == a, y[0] == b, Derivative[1][x][0] == c, 
  Derivative[1][y][0] == 
   d, (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == -((G M x[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(
    3/2)), (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == -((G M y[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(
    3/2))}, {x, y}, t]
```

But instead of solving it, Mathematica just returns the expression itself. Any help?

Comment: Change the second derivatives to ` x''[t] and y''[t]` . Still Mathematica isn't able to solve this odes.

Comment: This problem can be solved with a more systematic approach transforming slightly given differential equations.  Take a look at analogous problem solved exactly within general relativity: [The time-like geodesics (orbits) in the Schwarzschild spacetime](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214063/the-time-like-geodesics-orbits-in-the-schwarzschild-spacetime/214076#214076)

Comment: It is well known (Newton) that this problem can be solved in polarcoordinates with the additional constraint "Angular momentum constant"

Comment: @UlrichNeumann:  To the best of my knowledge you can only get $r(\theta)$ that way.  The OP appears to want $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ (or $x(t)$ and $y(t)$), and to the best of my knowledge there is not a known closed-form solution for that.  I suspect they will need to resort to using `NDSolve`.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You're right, thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After correcting several syntax errors, you may get a numerical solution by e.g. with arbitrary values for G and M:

```
G = 1;
M = 1;
a = 1; b = 0;
c = 0; d = 0.5;
tmax = 3;
sol = NDSolve[{x[0] == a, y[0] == b, x'[0] == c, y'[0] == d, 
    x''[t] == -((G M x[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2)), 
    y''[t] == -((G M y[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2))}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 
    tmax}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image]

Or an ubounded orbit with a bit more initial velocity:

```
G = 1;
M = 1;
a = 1; b = 0;
c = 0; d = 1.5;
tmax = 10;
sol = NDSolve[{x[0] == a, y[0] == b, x'[0] == c, y'[0] == d, 
x''[t] == -((G M x[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2)), 
y''[t] == -((G M y[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2))}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 
tmax}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image]